# Python: Combining two sorted lists (and keeping them sorted) without using built-in sort

Tags: python, sorting, merge

I found this merge sort solutions online and I'm wondering if while loops is the way to go or if there is also a way of using 2 for loops and comparing those.

```
def merge(l, m):
    result = []
    i = j = 0
    total = len(l) + len(m)
    while len(result) != total:
        if len(l) == i:
            result += m[j:]
            break
        elif len(m) == j:
            result += l[i:]
            break
        elif l[i] < m[j]:
            result.append(l[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(m[j])
            j += 1
    print result
```

merge([1,2,6,7], [1,3,5,9])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily change while to for:

```
def merge_for(l,m):
    result = []
    i = j = 0
    total = len(l) + len(m)

    for k in range(total):

        if len(l) == i:
            result += m[j:]
            print("append el {} at index {}".format(m[j], k))

            break
        elif len(m) == j:
            result += l[i:]
            break
        elif l[i] < m[j]:
            result.append(l[i])
            print("append el {} at index {}".format(l[i], k))
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(m[j])
            print("append el {} at index {}".format(m[j], k))
            j += 1

    print(result)


print(merge_for([1,2,6,7], [1,3,5,9]))

append el 1 at index 0
append el 1 at index 1
append el 2 at index 2
append el 3 at index 3
append el 5 at index 4
append el 6 at index 5
append el 7 at index 6
append el 9 at index 7

[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Ah, gotchya. So pretty much k is unused, and you create your own "mock" for loops (i += 1 & j += 1)?

Comment: @IntrepidDiamond put k to work, now it prints the index of insersion

Answer (score 2):

Python's builtin `sorted` would actually be pretty efficient at this (since the `TimSort` it uses takes advantage of existing ordering in subsets of a list). That said, there is a built-in that avoids the need to even construct a new `list` like `sorted` (or your solution) would: [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge)

It's designed precisely for scenarios where you have existing lists that are each independently sorted. It's a generator function, so it doesn't require the creation of a new `list` at all. If you are trying to do this to learn, enjoy yourself, but if this is for "real" code, use the included batteries and avoid reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using  using a generator:

```
from itertools import chain
def merge(l1,l2):
    i,j = 0,0
    try:
        while True:
            if l1[i] < l2[j]:
                yield l1[i]
                i +=1
            else:
                yield l2[j]
                j+=1
    except IndexError:
        for e in chain(l1[i:],l2[j:]):
            yield e

[x for x in merge([1,2,6,7], [1,3,5,9])]
```

> [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9]

Comment: The heapq.merge answer is the right. This is just for fun and learning.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sorted list you [bisect.insort](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort) the other:

```
from bisect import insort

a,b = [1,2,6,7], [1,3,5,9]

for ele in b:
    insort(a, ele)
print(a)
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9]
```